# Mac OS X: Change default Name when connecting to server

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

When trying to connect to a server I get the following prompt :

[image]

By default Snow Leopard fill the Name field with `Firstname Lastname` found in System Pref -> Account -> My Account -> Full Name !

I don't what to change my Full Name to the username I use to login to server !

How do you change the default Name Snow Leopard is using when connecting to server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there is a [real way](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=ServerAdmin/10.5/en/c3fs25.html) to change this username.

For lazy people :

#### To set the current user's short name:

$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseDefaultName -bool NO
$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseShortName -bool YES

#### To set a custom name:

$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseDefaultName -bool YES
$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization DefaultName "user"
*Replace "user" with the desired custom name and enclose it in quotation marks.*

#### To set no name:

$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseDefaultName -bool YES
$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization DefaultName ""

#### To set the current user's long name:

*This is only necessary if you have made any of the changes listed above.*

$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseDefaultName -bool NO
$ defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseShortName -bool NO

*or*

$ defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseDefaultName
$ defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization UseShortName

Comment: Wondering what the current method for doing this is considering this answer is 7 years old now. I'd like to set this behavior as a default for all macs on my network, but no luck with Google searching the topic. This is the only relevant search result I've found so far.

Answer (score 2):

Run Safari, and enter something like the following into its address bar:

```
afp://username@serverdomain
```

(e.g. "afp://fred@lacalsrv3.local").  Don't hit return, just drag the shortcut icon at the beginning of the address bar to the desktop; this'll create a URL location file which you can open to start a connection with the specified username.  If you'd like, you can put the file somewhere out of the way and put a shortcut to it in the Dock.

If you want the password to be automatic as well, it's actually even easier: connect once with the "Remember my password" checkbox selected, and it'll remember both the name and password for subsequent connection attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but could you create the link to the server with username@servername somehow?

I'm not at a mac right now or I would try.